# Cron job fails to run

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to run my python script in cron server every minute but somehow it doesn't run. My script runs well locally.

```
*/1 * * * * python /home/ana/cronjobs/ele/transfer.py
```

At the top of my transfer.py file I have :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Still it doesn't run. Any leads?

Comment: Whats the error you're getting?

Comment: I don't know how to check that. :/ @heemayl

Comment: Any specific error or log ?

Comment: Look at `/var/log/cron.log` (Fedora and brothers), `/var/log/syslog` (Debian/derivatives).

Comment: when I type `vim /var/log/cron.log` it shows empty

Comment: Side note: `*/1` is the same as `*` for "every minute".

Comment: I have a .txt file along with my transfer.py file in the same directory. I need the .txt file to get some output from the transfer.py file. Do u think I need to schedule the .txt file as well like I did to the .py file? or the command as I mentioned above needs to be changed for this? @BenjaminW

Comment: @heemayl any help?

Comment: Let's see... Run it as: `* * * * * python /home/ana/cronjobs/ele/transfer.py >/tmp/cron_out 2>&1` and get me the content of `/tmp/cron_out`

Comment: I get this `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /home/ana/cronjobs/ele/transfer.py on line 32, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details` , How do I add encoding here? I am using utf-8 in my script @heemayl

Comment: As now we have seen the error, i see that you have declared the encoding, but is it among the top-most two lines?

Comment: yes it is in the top most 2 lines @heemayl

Comment: Now when I re ran the code I see I dont have the same encoding error. I think its gone. I have this now `from pathlib import Path
ImportError: No module named pathlib` any leads on how can I install pathlib in cron? @heemayl

Comment: @PradyumnaMajumder Thats from your code, not from `cron`. You can install `pathlib` using usual ways e.g. using `pip`: `pip install pathlib` .(Note: `pathlib` was included to stdlib in 3.4).

Comment: @heemayl thanks for explaining me how to check the error logs. Now I realized I didnt need that module. I removed it and my code works well now. Thank you so much and sorry for bothering for a long time! cheers

Comment: Do you want me to put an answer?

Comment: Absolutely. I will upvote it! :) @heemayl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The answer is coming from the discussion I have with OP in the comment.*

To check the STDOUT/STDERR, ran the `cron` like below to save them in `/tmp/cron_out`:

```
* * * * * python /home/ana/cronjobs/ele/transfer.py >/tmp/cron_out 2>&1
```

Now, the file `/tmp/cron_out` contains:

```
ImportError: No module named pathlib
```

So the solution to this is obvious i.e. install `pathlib` (`pip install pathlib`). Just to note, `pathlib` is included in the standard library in 3.4.

**Note:**

As `cron` runs with a limited set of environments variable with most values reset to a default, it's always a good idea to use absolute path to the executable:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ana/cronjobs/ele/transfer.py
```

---

Also, you have the `/usr/bin/python`, so an easier way would be to make the script executable:

```
chmod u+x /home/ana/cronjobs/ele/transfer.py
```

and use the path to the script only in `crontab`:

```
* * * * * /home/ana/cronjobs/ele/transfer.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in your cron job you need to give absolute paths since you don't necessarily know where you are when cron kicks.

change

`*/1 * * * * python /home/ana/cronjobs/ele/transfer.py`

to

`*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ana/cronjobs/ele/transfer.py`

Comment: I did it before, but didnt work. But if I use `*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/ana/cronjobs/ele/transfer.py` do I remove  `#!/usr/bin/python` from the top of the code?

Comment: The `#!/usr/bin/python` is a she bang line that executes when the file `transfer.py` is given executable rights, it doesn't matter here

Comment: It's usually a good idea to create a shell script that runs what needs to run as a cron job, and _only_ list that file in the crontab. Also assume that the crontab knows nothing about your paths and environment variables; set them up in your shell file.

Comment: @PradyumnaMajumder give me a stack trace otherwise I can't help you

Comment: @MikeTung as in what in particular? I see nothing in the error log

Comment: @PradyumnaMajumder how do you know `it doesn't work`?

Comment: @MikeTung I am populating a mysql database. The code was working locally but now in cron it doesn't

Comment: I have a .txt file along with my transfer.py file in the same directory. I need the .txt file to get some output from the transfer.py file. Do u think I need to schedule the .txt file as well like I did to the .py file? @MikeTung